# Microsoft Bot Framework v4 How can we implement scrollbar in a rich card

Tags: botframework

My rich card has too many buttons as I am display some information for the user selection using a loop. But when there are too many buttons displays, the user need to scroll the chat to select one among the button. Instead of this I need a scroll to be placed for a rich card

[image: Rich card with too many buttons]

Comment: Can you provide the code sample for building this card? Is it a herocard or adaptive card? What are your target channels, or where do you want to render it?

Comment: It is a hero card and the target channels are web chat, MS Teams. Code is general for loop for the buttons in the hero card. Thanks